# How to pass service parameters in ROSLib.js

Tags: ros, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the `ROSLib.js` [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs/Tutorials/BasicRosFunctionality#CA-3bc839e9e2d3c2cac3f7fabffacfbda3d5c050ae_69) I did this class

```
import { Ros, Param, Message, Topic, Service, ServiceRequest } from "roslib";

export default class ROSInterface {
  constructor() {
    this.ros = new Ros({
      url: "ws://localhost:9090",
    });
  }
  createService(service_name, service_type) {
    const service = new Service({
      ros: this.ros,
      name: service_name,
      serviceType: service_type,
    });

    return service;
  }

  callService(service_name, service_type, params) {
    const service = this.createService(service_name, service_type);
    const request = new ServiceRequest(params);
    service.callService(request, function (result) {
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```

But I'm confused how can I pass a complex parameters to my service!

#### My Service looks like this:

```
geometry_msgs/Point pick
geometry_msgs/Point place
std_msgs/UInt16 speed
std_msgs/Bool arm
```

I have tried `let params = {pick:{x:0.1,y:0.2,z:0.3}, place:{x:-0.1,y:-0.2,z:-0.3},speed: 200, arm: 1}` and it didn't work! can you please tell me how can I form my params variabile properly to make my service works well? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409807/how-to-pass-service-parameters-in-roslib.js/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2022-11-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2022-11-24**:
Can you add service_name and service_type to this? What are you passing

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2022-11-24**:
@RanjitKathiriya that is straight forward `const service_name = "/pick_place"; const service_type = "my_interface/PickPlace";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution is:

1. Simpler ROS Message representation:

   ```
    geometry_msgs/Point pick
    geometry_msgs/Point place
    int16 speed
    bool arm
    ---
    bool success
   ```
2. Function Name different from `callService` to remove ambiguity, for example: `callService_`:

   ```
     import { Ros, Param, Message, Topic, Service, ServiceRequest } from "roslib";

     export default class ROSInterface {

       constructor() {

         this.ros = new Ros({
           url: "ws://localhost:9090",
         });
       }

       createService=(service_name, service_type) =>{
         let service = new Service({
           ros: this.ros,
           name: service_name,
           serviceType: service_type,
         });
         return service;
       }

      requestService=(params) =>{
         let request = new ServiceRequest(params);
         return request;
       }


       callService_ = (service_name, service_type, params) => {
         const srv = this.createService(service_name, service_type);
         const req = this.requestService(params);
         srv.callService(
           req,
           (result) => {
             console.log(result);
           },
           (error) => {
             console.log(error);
           }
         );
        }
     }
   ```
3. Finally the parameters can be passed as object with children objects:

   ```
    const params_ = {
    pick: {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3},
    place: {x: -1, y: -2, z: -3},
    speed: 10,
    arm: false,
    };
    ROSInterface.callService_(service_name, service_type, params_);
   ```

---

Originally posted by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) with karma: 114 on 2022-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0